# How to stop timeout when coming back to a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I need to start time after leaving a controller and if come back in 5 seconds then cancel it. the destroy works and timer starts. But if I come back the timer will still be running and will print its message.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var timer;

    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        timer = $timeout(function () {
            console.log('timer works on destroy')
            localStorage.removeItem('transaction')
        },5000)
    });

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
    });
})
```

Can you help find where I do wrong or another way of canceling a timeout when go to a controller (page).

Comment: where is your timer variable declared? Is it global?

Comment: @floribon Sorry. Formatted the text wrong and didn't show up

Comment: what causes your controller to be destroyed? most likely next time your controller shows up it's a new instantiation so the timer variable is declared again and the previous one forgotten. If you add a log just after you declare timer, do you see your log only once or multiple times?

Comment: What do you mean with "But if I come back t..." I guess when the controller's scope is destroyed the timer is canceled. Isn't it?

Comment: OK I understand what you mean. I should declare the timer in an service so if I leave the controller the timer won't be destroyed

Comment: Or declare it in $rootScope so that you will have $rootScope.timer = $timeout...

Comment: Or just log the time you left in Storage/cookie and check the time again when you reenter.

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro  I added it to a factory that I already had. Thanks for your advices

Comment: @LucaDeNardi I added to the service I have. Thanks for help